# Create smooth scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling

I have a code to scroll content horizontally, it works but whenever it scrolls, it scrolls items one by on like breaking, so I want it to scroll smoothly, that is the sample code below, please I need help with it

```
 <style>
.child {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
</style>

<script>
(function(w){
    w.addEventListener('load', function(){
        const   btn_left = document.getElementById('btn-left'),
                btn_right = document.getElementById('btn-right'),
                content = document.getElementById('con');
        const content_scroll_width = content.scrollWidth;
        let content_scoll_left = content.scrollLeft;
        btn_right.addEventListener('click', () => {
            content_scoll_left += 100;
            if (content_scoll_left >= content_scroll_width) { content_scoll_left = content_scroll_width; }
            content.scrollLeft = content_scoll_left;
        });
        btn_left.addEventListener('click', () => {
            content_scoll_left -= 100;
            if (content_scoll_left <= 0) {
                content_scoll_left = 0;
            }
            content.scrollLeft = content_scoll_left;
        });
    });
})(window);
</script>

<div class="parent">
     <div class="child" id="con">
                Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.
                Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.
                Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.
                Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.
                Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.
                Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.
                Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.
                Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.
                Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btn-left">Left scroll</button>
<button id="btn-right">Right scroll</button>
```

Comment: use `scroll-behaviour: smooth` css rule. It may not affect older browsers but who cares its not a functionally important feature

Comment: I did it and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `scroll-behavior: smooth` in your css file. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2) is an example.

Or, if you want to do it with JavaScript, try

```
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```